# I want to now how to set. X to a spot and change it to a cord but. Keep my Y and Z

Tags: c#, unity

Let's say postion was X1 Z34 Y2 I want to move char to X2 no matter what Z or Y are I want to change my x and keep z and y the same and keep momentum

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried and did not work?

Answer (score 1):

See [Transform.position](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html).

```
transform.position = new Vector3(newPosx, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
```

Comment: I'm an idiot. Was wonder if. I could get an example

Comment: That is an example.What's not clear about it?

Comment: Every thing I'm bad about this initiative stuff is hard

Comment: In this example, we put in the game object position (x,y,z) a new vector composed of 3 values: (x is the new position you want, y is the old position y, and z is the old position z). I don't think i can be more clear about this. 
And, not to be a dick about it, but you seriously need some computer programming experience if you find this hard, it will help you enormously !

Answer (score 1):

You could do
`transform.Translate(SPEED, 0, 0);`

which will give you a continuous movement along the X axis only.

Comment: He didn't explain what exactly he wants or what he meant by "no matter what Z or Y are", but I'm not sure he wants them to always be 0.

Comment: transform.Translate() doesn't set the position it moves the object, so zero would mean the object isn't moving at the axis.

Comment: ah my bad I get that confused confused sometimes (more often with rotation/Rotate but same difference)